# What file system to select to run Photorec

Tags: data-recovery

Earlier I was running Windows 10 pro, Accidentally overwrite it with Ubuntu, everything is erased. **now want to run photorec to recover my important files so what file system should I select ext2/ext3/ext4/ or FAT, NTFS, HFS+** as the data were stored on the system when windows 10 was running and now running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one you used when using Windows.  The only one that knows that would be you. Most of us would guess NTFS.